# How to put an event when the mouse goes over an element in FullCalendar?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have a calendar with FullCalendar (site of the same name) and I would like when I pass on a date that it goes into another color

here is my code :

I tried their doc but it did not work

```
`<full-calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" 
            (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)" 
            locale="fr"
            [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
            [events]="events">
 </full-calendar>`
```

and ts :

```
 `calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin];`
```

I would like to know if you have an idea?
 'eventMouseEnter',
 'eventMouseLeave'
I tried that but I do not know how to apply it

Comment: how did you try it, exactly? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

  eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
    alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + info.view.type);

    // change the border color just for fun
    info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }

});
```

Refer this link for more info : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventMouseLeave